# Objective-c NSArray init versus initWithCapacity:0

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management

Do

```
[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

and

```
[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
```

compile into the exact same thing?

If they differ, then how, and which form is "better" in terms of memory and runtime performance?

Comment: Without knowing the implementation details I would like to be able to believe and say that the Foundation team made the performance difference between the two negligible. From a personal opinion I think it is best practice to call any provided initializers by the class over a generic one if it makes sense. Since NSMutableArray publicly declares initWithCapacity and just inherits init I would lean towards using initWithCapacity. Also why not write a loop that analyzes a lot of mutable array creations using init and initWithCapacity and add your observations.

Comment: See also [NSMutableArray initWithCapacity nuances](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3948062/nsmutablearray-initwithcapacity-nuances).

Comment: Beware premature optimization.

Comment: Interesting read about NSArray performance: ["Our Arrays, Aren't" by Ridiculous Fish](http://ridiculousfish.com/blog/archives/2005/12/23/array/). @Joe

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No, they will not behave identically. `init` will create an array with some unknown but most likely nonzero capacity—whatever the authors decided was a reasonable default for most situations. `initWithCapacity:0` will request an array with absolutely no allocated space. What this means is up to the `NSMutableArray` implementation: it might not allow a capacity of 0 and behave exactly as `init`, or it might not immediately allocate anything and instead allocate some amount (the same as `init`, possibly, or maybe not) when you first need it.

Which will perform "better" completely depends on how you expect to use the array. `-init` says "I have no expectations for this array; I'll either be adding to and removing from it a lot, or it will likely be pretty small." `-initWithCapacity:` says "I expect this array to have no more than this many elements for the foreseeable future."

About the only place where I would expect `initWithCapacity:0` to be reasonable is if you are creating an array that you don't expect to fill with anything for a fairly long period of time.

Note that the standard performance caveat applies here: it's probably not an issue unless you profile and determine that it is. I can't really imagine a situation (except for thousands upon thousands of `NSMutableArray` objects) where the difference between these two will be substantial.

Comment: +1 note that using `initWithCapacity:n` does not preclude you from adding more than *n* objects to the array.  It's just a suggestion so `NSArray` can try to do some optimization under-the-hood.

Comment: Also refer to [this blog post](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/08/nsarray-or-nsset-nsdictionary-or.html) by Matt Gallagher